# transactionally swap two tables in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to transactionally swap two tables in my schema.

The idea is that I have two tables that have identical definitions with different names.  One table is currently "in use" while the other is "staging."

Every 30 minutes the staging table is truncated and loaded with a fresh set of data.  At this point I'd like to transactionally swap the "in use" table with the "staging" table so that there is zero downtime for any queries against the "in use" table.

```
Example:
myTable
myTable_staging

--truncate staging table
truncate myTable_staging;
--bulk load into staging table
insert into myTable_staging select bunch, of, data from someTable;

--transactionally swap the two tables
rename myTable to myTable_old, myTable_staging to myTable, myTable_old to myTable_staging;
```

Can anyone come up with a solution for doing this in Oracle 11g?

Comment: I'd just use `version` column and restrict my queries on the current version. Insert into next version; to switch, increment version at SQL client. One schema, one table.

Comment: Create a view that points to your "in use" table. Everywhere in the application, use the view instead of the table. Then, when the staging table is ready, just recreate the view, pointing to the staging table.

Comment: I ended using Alen's suggestion which is working fine for me.

Comment: I know this is old but facing the same issue. If using @AlenOblak solution, do you create a new staging table on every load? If you still have to rename or create tables, it's still not transactional in oracle, right?